# How to remap keyboard keys using xev with ALT-R or ALT-L

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xev

I am still a newbie on Linux, but there is something that I find really annoying: my keyboard, whatever I do, does not have the layout I want it to have. I tried many solutions, but I use a French Canadian (FC) keyboard and the Linux FC layout is not like the Windows one, so having one and the same for everywhere would be a big plus for me.

Here is what I tried.

First thing, I typed:

```
xev
```

Then I hit the 'z' key, because it is the one I want to modify. Basically, I want the 'z' key to continue to work normally, but if I click on the right ALT key, I want this to show: '«'  (guillemotleft)

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
root 0x526, subw 0x0, time 4040472, (-215,198), root:(536,634),
state 0x10, keycode 52 (keysym 0x7a, z), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7a) "z"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So, OK, the key is number 52.

Then I write:

xmodmap -pm

And here is what it shows:

```
  xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

So, basically, I think my ALT right key is ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c). What I need, now, is to find a way to make it work so that if I click the ALT-Right key with the 'z' key, I get a '«'. This is where I'm stuck.

I tried many things, including things like

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 52 mod5 = guillemotleft z"
```

but it didn't work. At some point I was able to get a '«', but then 'z' didn't work anymore.

What can I do to make it work? What is the command to modify the mod5 without modifying the z Z setup, or, more to the point, how can I hit my right ALT key + z and get '«'?

Thanks

Comment: Remove "using xev" from your title unless you are absolutely sure this is done with xev.

Answer (score 1):

`xmodmap` is gradually being outdated and will not work in Ubuntu running Wayland. On the other hand, directly editing keyboard layout files is rather complicated.

Instead you may want to try the keyboard layout "French (Canada,legacy), which has the `«` as the AltGr combination on z, and `»` on x.

Comment: I am on Linux Mint XFCE. I know this is a Ubuntu board but I thought the solution would be the same. I don't see a 'French (Canada,legacy)' option unfortunately. :-(

Comment: The solution is not necessarily the same. This board is dedicated to Ubuntu only.

Comment: @JohnStraight and now you know why this site is dedicated to Ubuntu